# specify file types in RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php

I am trying to create a form that allows a user to select checkboxes and when they submit it will search the web directory for the specific file types they checked off (jpg, gif, html, etc). I have the form done and it passes the variables for the types to an array, i have the rest of the form that zips the files and streams it for download. i am just stuck on how to specify the file types. this is what i have started with to make sure it can actually pull the file names and place them in a variable and it works:

```
$rootpath = '.';
$files = $_POST['file_types'];
$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath)
);
foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) continue;{
    $files[] .= substr($pathname, 2);
    }
}
```

What should i use to pull the file types only specified in the following vaiable?

```
$_POST['file_types']
```

Edit:

For those who this may help this is the solution in the end that worked:

```
$rootpath = "../";
        foreach ($types as $k => $v)
        {
        $types_array[] .= $v;
    }
    //Run all function then run it through checker and pull out the files we want
    $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory,RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);
    $extensions = $types_array;
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        if (in_array($fileinfo->getExtension(), $extensions)) {
            $files[] = substr($fileinfo->getPathname(), 2); /* Fill the array removing the "./" to make an echo of the file names easier to read for the end user */
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is not clear. `$fileinfo->getExtension()`? PS: you have some weird curly braces in your `foreach` body

Comment: the curly braces are left over from when i had more in the foreach, they can go but my question is plain and simple. how do i turn this into a RecursiveIteratorIterator that can specify which file types to pull instead of just doing all of the files.

Comment: `$fileinfo->getExtension()` + `FilterIterator`?

Comment: $fileinfo->getExtension() did the trick, thank you for pointing me in the obvious direction!